# call custom hooks conditionally react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I defined a custom hook to do some operations and calling some APIs like below

```js
    const useCustomHook = (param1,param2) => {
      const response = callAPI(param1, param2 ){ .... }
       return [callAPI, response]
    }
```

and I used this hook somewhere and it works as well : for example

```
const [save ,response] = useCustomHook(param1,param2);
```

But, I need to call **save** with different parameters in different condition:
for example :

```
if (type===1) 
    const [save ,response] = useCustomHook(param1,'a');
else 
    const [save ,response] = useCustomHook(param1,'b');
```

`type` is gotten from another hook.like this

```js
   const type = useType()
```

However, as you know hooks can't call conditionally so the above code doesn't run.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: you didn't say in your question what condition you are thinking of? you just said pass different paramaters. You can still use conditions, just not surrounding the actual hook calls like useState or useEffect

Comment: Kindly provide more context

Comment: sorry for delay, I added some context and example. @azium

Comment: Do something like 
`const [save ,response] = useCustomHook(param1,type===1 ? 'a' :  'b');`

Comment: No unfortunately because the type value is specified after calling the hook. @ZunaibImtiaz

Comment: That's against [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), you can't call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. you need to put your conditions inside the hook.

Comment: I know this and my question is about finding an alternative.

Comment: I don't understand, you say you need to call `save` with different params but your question you're calling your hook with different params

Comment: Yes, But hook rules doesn’t allow to do that. So I’m looking for alternative way.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should rather use the condition inside the custom hook. You can pass the **type** as  third argument in the custom Hook and handle the conditional logic from there.

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar problem. I was calling a custom hook that makes API fetch and if the user input changed I needed to call it again with different parameters, so I basically needed some conditions or different arguments with my custom hook, which violates React hook rules.

I saved my problem with different approach.

What you could try is to put the second argument ('a' or 'b' in your case) into a prop "key" of the children component which would force reload of a component in case this key prop changes.

for example:

```
function ParentComponent() {

// logic of setting param2 based on type

/* You need to make sure keyprop changes as param2 changes. This would refresh ChildComponent and call customHook with new parameters */

return <ChildComponent key={keyprop} arg1={param1} arg2={param2} />
}

function ChildComponent(props) {
const [save ,response] = useCustomHook(props.arg1,props.arg2);

// do something with state

return (
/* ...display logic... */
)
}
```

I hope that approach solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can pass conditional props to the custom hook

```
let props = a
if (type === 1) {
  props = b
}

const [save, response] = useCustomHook(param1, props)
```

Comment: the value of type is determined after calling the hook